# using v-bind:href to bind an expression

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to bind an expression to a URL using v-bind of `vue.js`.
The binder expression will be a year of the folder and I want that expression to render in the links.
I am trying to get this to bind correctly.
Can someone see what I am improperly concatenating?

```html
<a v-bind:href="'https://www.exmaple.com'+{{$route.params.year | year}}'+'&FolderCTID=0x012000507B97BC3FFDCE4D854E'">My Link</a>
```

Comment: You may use Template Literals as well: `<a :href="\`https://www.exmaple.com${$route.params.year || year}&FolderCTID=0x012000507B97BC3FFDCE4D854E\`">My Link</a>` And as the other answer pointed out use `||` instead of `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this into my hyperlink and it works like a charm! I am sure someone will need this

```html
+ $options.filters.year($route.params.year) +'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```html
<a v-bind:href="'https://www.example.com/' + ($route.params.year || year) + '&FolderCTID=0x012000507B97BC3FFDCE4D854E'">My Link</a>
```

Key changes:

- `||` instead of `|`. The latter is a bitwise operator.
- Added parentheses to ensure the `||` is applied correctly. Otherwise the `+` operators will be applied first.
- Ditched the `{{ ... }}`. They shouldn't appear within `v-bind` expressions.
- Removed the extra `'` after the `}}`.
- Added an extra `/` after the `.com`.

This will give, for example:

```
https://www.example.com/2019&FolderCTID=0x012000507B97BC3FFDCE4D854E
```

It seems likely you'd want a `?` in there somewhere but that wasn't included in the original code.

You haven't mentioned what `year` is but it appears that it's a default for when the `year` route param is missing. That's certainly what I've assumed.

You may also want to consider using a computed property for this as it's a little complicated for template logic.

**Update:**

Based on the comment it seems that you intended `|` to be a Vue filter.

A filter can only be applied to the end of the whole expression. You cannot use it in the middle. If you try to use it in the middle it will just be interpreted as the JavaScript `|` operator and not as a filter.

I suggest using a method instead. If you have a method called `formatYear` it can be called using `formatYear($route.params.year)` within your `v-bind` expression.

Comment: hi the year is a filter. {{route.params.year | year}} Is this || supposed to  be used as a filter?

Comment: @Vzupo I've added an update to my answer. You can't use a filter in the middle of an expression like that.

Comment: hi-- I am using this  Vue.filter('year', value => {
  return years.get(value.substring(0, 19)) || 'Unknown'
})

Comment: @Vzupo I don't believe that has any impact on my answer. It doesn't matter what is in your filter, you can't use it in the middle of an expression. You would have to implement it some other way, such as a method.